# Exoplayer v2 custome Ui

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to create a video streaming app I am using the Exo - player for DASH-streaming video. I am done with this by following this [Link](https://medium.com/fungjai/playing-video-by-exoplayer-b97903be0b33) but now I want to add a transparent chat/comment section over the left of Exo-player.

When I touch the screen it should be visible and again to touch its visibility should go. but I am not able to figure this out. how can I do it. Please help :)

Comment: You need to create your own custom exo_playback_control_view layout which is an overlay layout

Comment: Can you explain a little more to me, I am new to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `exo_playback_control_view.xml` file in your `layout` directory. This will override the default layout that `ExoPlayer` is using. And from here, just add whatever you want. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_fullscreen"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_exo_play"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_exo_pause"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

   Your chat section goes here perhaps
  </FrameLayout>
```